# Cakephp multiple drop down list with view

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to get drop down list in Cake for below two finds by list:

```
  function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The User has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The User could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
        $group = $this->User->Group->find('list');
        $commune = $this->User->Commune->find('list');
        $this->compact('group','commune');
    }
}
```

The model already has belongsTo defined in User model for Group and Commune models with their ids but I cannot seem to get group and commune to show up as drop down list in the add view page.

Below is what I have for add view page.

```
<div class="Users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php __('Add User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('group_id', array('type' => 'select'));
        echo $this->Form->input('commune_id');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>

        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Users', true), array('action' => 'index'));?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a reason why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use plurals in order to automatically load those options into the form fields.

$groups, $communes

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the view:

```
$this->Form->input('Group');
```

Alternatively:

```
$this->Form->input('group_id', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $group));
```

You're setting $group and $commune but the view is looking for $group_id and $commune_id.

Comment: you probably mean 'options' => $group